# apply a function over a permutations of all rows in a matrix in R

Tags: r, apply

I have  a matrix with x columns and y rows.
x and y are large values.

```
              A           B      C         
GeneA         1           0      0        
GeneB         0           0      1
GeneC         0           0      1
GeneD         1           0      1
```

I want to apply a distance function over rows of the matrix and output a matrix with dimension y*y with each cell having the return value from the function.
Output looks like this:

```
               GeneA        GeneB     GeneC   GeneD       
GeneA            1.0           0.7     0.0       0.4 
GeneB            0.6         0.2     1.0       1.0
GeneC            0.0         0.1     1.0       0.5
GeneD            1.0         0.5     0.1       0.8
```

My function is:

```
dist <- function(vec1, vec2) {
  res=length(intersect(vec1,vec2))/length(union(vec1,vec2))
  return (res)
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why is your second matrix not symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `outer` and you can define your distance function as you need

```
outer(
  1:nrow(mat),
  1:nrow(mat),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) sqrt(sum((mat[x, ] - mat[y, ])^2)))
)
```

or a much simpler one using `dist` (thank @akrun's reminder)

```
as.matrix(dist(mat))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `dist` works i.e. `as.matrix(dist(mat, method = "desired method"))`

Comment: @akrun Yes, you are right, I forgot this magic thing :P Thank you man!

Comment: Will this method, take all permutations of rows of the input matrix? The function accepts two rows as parameters